# MS-Help Library Agent: "System.Web.Mvc" completely wiped out after humongous update

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I installed VS2010 Pro; Help was working fine but It had MVC 2.0 help installed.

I thought I could update it to MVC 3.0 and now it's gone; all of `System.Web.Mvc`.

Offline Help is sort of bloodline for my MVC & C# learning.

Has anyone resolved this issue? 
I think I would pass re-installing; though I am downloading Visual Studio 11 Ultimate Beta.

What are my options/chances here?

*catastrophic-failure* is how I am seeing it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What comes after humongous download is MAMMOTH download. After some 10GBs of download, Visual Studio 11 Ultimate Beta. and updating library to it's capacity; I can access `System.Web.Mvc`.

Thanks.

Comment: I can still access my projects, because there was no re-installing VS. cool